# Compress and Decompress a String

Tags: java, c, string

How to compress strings like `“aaabbbc”` to `“a3b3c”` and decompress the same, without using extra memory during processing, primarily in C and also in Java?

Comment: What have you tried? And are you aware that simple run-length compression will *expand* most normal text?

Comment: That should be `a3b3c` right?

Comment: I'd use existing ZIP facilities in Java.  I don't think it can be done without extra memory during processing.

Comment: is your homework limited to just compressing alpha characters?

Comment: In Java, you'll have to use a `StringBuilder`, `char[]`, or the like to do this in-place. `String` objects are immutable, so if you start with a `String` you're going to have to use _some_ extra memory. Also, how are you supposed to compress strings that have digits in them to start with? Or does that not happen?

Comment: How on earth would you know that there are three `a` characters without storing at least one of them in memory? Are you going to read and write a single character to a file? Even then you have to store two characters in memory just to do the comparison. Voting to close.

Comment: @Alex,  in C you can do that,  char* first_char_occurance;  char* current_char;      then if(*first_char_occrance == *current_char)

Comment: Am I the only one who wonders how to decompress `33333333`?

Comment: If the plaintext can contain only letters, then it's straight forward: Either a character is solitary, then you just keep it and move on, or there is at least two and you have enough room to replace the run of identical characters with the compressed form, which you can do in-place.

Comment: @AlexReynolds - I think that by "without using extra memory", OP means in-place encoding. That is, only a fixed (and small) amount of extra memory should be used, regardless of the original (or encoded) string size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple reverse scan does provide a (seemingly) good solution to the encoding part at least. I am doing one scan from right to left and overwriting the portions of the string with the occurrence count.

```
char * enc(char * ip)
{
    int r,op;
    int l=strlen(ip);
    r=l-1;
    char curr;
    op=r;
    int curr_count=1,mod_curr_count;
    while(r>=0)
    {
        curr=ip[r];

        while(ip[--r]==curr)
        {

            curr_count++;
        }
        if(curr_count!=1)
        {
            while(curr_count)
            {
            mod_curr_count=curr_count%10;
            ip[op--]=(char)(mod_curr_count+48);
            curr_count/=10;
            }
            ip[op--]=curr;
            curr_count=1;

        }
        else
        {
        ip[op--]=curr;
        }
    }

    ip=ip+op+1;
    return ip;
}
```

**Input :** aaaaaaaaaaaabbbfffffffffffffffqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqccccpoii

**Output:** a12b3f15q18c4poi2

Answer (score 1):

To do an in-place encoding, the encoded string must never be longer than the original string. Suppose we assume the following encoding rules:

- No numeric digits in the original string (so no count delimiter characters are needed)
- A run length of 1 is never explicitly coded (so `abc` remains `abc`)

I believe that with these assumptions, a run-length encoding is not ambiguous and will never be longer than the string itself. Then the following algorithm (pseudocode) should do the job of encoding in place:

```
currentChar ← string[0]
nextOutputPos ← 1
nextReadPos ← 1
count ← 1
while (nextReadPos < length of string) {
    nextChar ← string[nextReadPos++];
    if (nextChar == currentChar) {
        count++;
    } else {
        if (count > 1) {
            write (count as a string) to string at position nextOutputPos
            nextOutputPos ← nextOutputPos + (length of count as a string)
        }
        string[nextOutputPos++] ← currentChar ← nextChar;
    }
}
```

At the end, the encoded string is contained in the half-open range [0, `nextOutputPos`) of `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility in Java, making use of regular expressions:

```
String str = "aaabbbc";  // string to be encoded

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  // to hold encoded string

for (String s : str.split("(?<=(.))(?!\\1)")) {
    sb.append(s.charAt(0));
    if (s.length() > 1) // only append length if it's > 1
        sb.append(s.length());
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

```
a3b3c
```